# Ansible - Managing Windows 2003 and WinRM connection timeout

Tags: windows, ansible, rhel, adhoc, winrm

I'm trying to implement Ansible in our company.
I have 2 huge problems that may cause us to leave this product, but before we give up I thought maybe someone could help us.

Some overall information - We installed ansible 2.1 on RHEL 6.5. We tried to use Ansible Tower but we gave up because of the complexity (most of our use is for ad-hoc commands).

The first issue is managing Windows server 2003. When we want to manage windows servers, we need to run the pre-script, but it only works with PowerShell v.3 and above, while Windows server 2003 is not supporting PowerShell v.3 (it's almost impossible to install this version).
In our company (unfortunately) there still dozens of Windows server 2003 machines.
Is there a way to make Ansible being able to manage those servers?

The second issue is the timeout of the WinRM. When we running an ad-hoc command on windows servers, there are machines that Ansible succeed to make a WinRM connection, but its hang out waiting the command to run (for example, even simple "hostname" commands).
We reduced the ansible timeout, but it's still hang out, so we assuming that it succeed making the WinRM connection but hang after.
There ia a way to configure the time out of *ALL* the process of ansible per machine, or otherwise configure the WinRM to have timeout after the connection succeeded?

Thanks,
Afik

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no- due to major shortcomings of Powershell 2 for things we need to do, and the incredibly low number of Server 2003 installs left out there, we made PS3 the minimum required version.

There's been a little bit of work done by community folks to make a PS2-friendly version of the WinRM connection plugin to at least get basic Ansible connectivity working there (so "raw" will work, and modules can be transferred/run), but pretty much all the existing modules rely on Powershell cmdlets that don't exist in PS2/S2003. So you'd be back to "raw" for everything, which isn't much more useful than Powershell remoting (other than being able to blast commands to multiple machines at a time). If you want to see that, it's at

https://github.com/elum/ansible and 
https://github.com/elum/ansible-modules-core

but we're unlikely to accept this into the core product or support it in any way.